# WARNING: No NSS support for mDNS detected, consider installing nss-mdns!

Tags: linux, cross-compilation, avahi, mips

I have cross-compiled avahi-0.8 library for the MIPS platform. I am able to run the avahi daemon from the console, but I'm getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: No NSS support for mDNS detected, consider installing nss-mdns!
```

How can I remove the above warning?

Screenshot of the logs:

[image]

```
[root@Ingenic:~]# avahi-daemon --file=/system/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
Found user 'root' (UID 0) and group 'root' (GID 0).
Successfully dropped root privileges.
avahi-daemon 0.8 starting up.
WARNING: No NSS support for mDNS detected, consider installing nss-mdns!
Loading service file /system/etc/avahi/services/sftp-ssh.service.
Loading service file /system/etc/avahi/services/ssh.service.
socket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol
Failed to create IPv6 socket, proceeding in IPv4 only mode
socket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol
Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.42.0.148.
New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv4 with address 127.0.0.0.
New relevant interface lo.IPv4 for mDNS.
Network interface enumeration completed.
Registering new address record for 10.42.0.148 on eth0.IPv4.
Registering new address record for 127.0.0.0 on lo.IPv4.
Server startup complete. Host name is Ingenic.local. Local service cookie is 315733776.
Service "Ingenic" (/system/etc/avahi/services/ssh.service) successfully established.
Service "Ingenic" (/system/etc/avahi/services/sftp-ssh.service) successfully established.
```

Comment: I have installed the bonjour on windows but not able to see my Ingenic device.
However I am able to ping Ingenic.local on my windows machine. 
I am not able to understand why my device is not able to discover on bonjour application on IE.
However other devices are able to discover on bonjour like printer and switch etc.

Comment: The warning has always been telling you how to remove it: "consider installing nss-mdns!". So did you consider installing it? Did you check what it's about?

Comment: Yes @A.B just before your comment i have installed the nns-mdns shared libraries and now the warning is removed. Thanks for your reply.
can you please refer my another thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700778/not-geeting-host-name-on-bonjour-application-add-on-ruuning-on-internet-explor

Comment: Your post on SO is off-topic, it's not about code&development. Also anywhere you post, please ensure you did your homework first. Make everything work on a standard system where there's a distribution providing usual packages. Once it works, switch to MIPS platform. That way if something is missing you'll know what to compare. The issue is not the MIPS plateform, it's the fact that you are compiling things but might not know what dependencies it requires.

Comment: @A.B It is not at all off-topic. I have cross compiled the avahi-daemon library version 0.8 for one of my IP camera board. I am able to run that avahi-daemon on my board using command on my board given on SO link. The only thing is it is not able to discover on (add on) bonjour on the internet explorer which is connected in same local network. However bonjour addon able to discover router and other printer devices on internet explorer? So my question is , how bonjour will discover my ip camera device ? Have i missed anything? , because avahi-daemon is running on my ip camera.

Comment: it is off-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: where can i post that?

Comment: Not sure where. Your problem is making it work. This requires understanding how avahi/bonjour and multicast dns works. Do you? Again you should test on a standard platform where you did not compile anything yourself first.

Comment: @A.B Yes i am also able to run avahi on my X86 machine and may laptop is also not able to discover in Bonjour add-on on IE. However It is able to discover HP LaserJet and switch connected on wireless network

Comment: Do I need to install D-BUS library dependency? I am not sure. For now i have compiled Avahi - daemon without D-BUS. Is that ok?